# Communication between a parent process and the OS

Tags: c, unix, operating-system, parent-child

Does anybody  know if a parent process can be notified that its child has finished without being blocked in the function `wait(&state)`, and avoid that the child process become a zombie ?

Comment: Please note, that what you are asking for is not a communication between the child and its parent, but between the OS and the parent. Your question's title is misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want [`waitpid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html) instead of `wait()`.

```
waitpid(0, NULL, WNOHANG)
```

This will return the pid of a dead child, or `-1` immediately if there are none.

Comment: but in my case the parent process should keep executing not waitting, is that possible  ???

Comment: @rainman: You might like to read `man waitpid`, especially regarding the option `WNOHANG`.